# Sequelize return value from getter method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble getting an actual value to return from a getterMethod. Currently I have the following:

```
  getterMethods: {
      awayTeamName() {
          return this.getAwayTeam().then(function(awayTeam) {
              return awayTeam.getTeams().then(function(team) {
                  return team.name;
              });
          });
      }
  }
```

My issue is that this always returns '**[object Promise]**' to the view instead of the value.

I thought by 'returning' all of the promises, I should end up with the value at the end. In my EJS template, I am literally just calling this as:

```
<%= event.awayTeamName %>
```

Comment: Firstly, you are handling the promises incorrectly. the two promises are not chained. Secondly, if you return a promise, then you should handle the then blocks, to the other code who is calling awayTeamName, in which case, you can't use it directly in the view without fetching the data from it

Comment: @SandipGhosh I appreciate the response, but I'm not sure this really helps me. What do you mean the promises are not chained? The first one returns a value which the second uses, and again the third. I'm not sure what you mean about fetching the data either? With other methods in getters I'm able to simple return data straight away.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to actually abstract this outside of the getterMethods and create a new middleware function for it. I'm also using the async library around this to set a new property on many object in a loop before passing back to the view.